# Appending a html list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        Playlist
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul id="playList">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to request a JSON file and add a list dynamically to the html with this code

```
function loadVideoList() {
  const playListContainer = $('#playList');
  $.getJSON('http://myserver.com/rest/78', function( res ) {
    const self = this;
    if(this.videoList !== res){
      $('#playList').empty();
      this.videoList = res;
      res.videos.forEach((item) => {
       console.log('ok');
        playListContainer.append('<li class="playlist-item"><span class="playlist-item-link" uri="' + item.name + '">' + item.tcsd + '</span></li>');
      });
    }
    });
```

The json is downloaded with success, 'ok' is printed n times but the list doese not appear on the html

**EDIT:**
this is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tmzrmxy/) where the problem could be reproduced

Comment: Perhaps you are calling this function before `$('#playList');` exists. What does `console.log(playListContainer.length)` show?

Comment: @Mamun how would the "ok" get logged n times  then?

Comment: @kjkj Can you inspect the dynamic elements? Might be it's appending but the positioning of the elements are some other location

Comment: @charlietfl The length is always 0

Comment: Only reason fiddle doesn't work is you didn't include jQuery library . Works here https://jsfiddle.net/3tmzrmxy/1/ when you do. My guess is you aren't wrapping the function call loadVideoList() in document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide a fiddle it's kinda hard to help you. But generally, use the ES6 arrow functions for lexical binding. I see you try to imitate it by assigning this to a variable called self, but maybe it's a good idea then to use self instead of this. I guess since you used this in the code blocks it's referencing an undefined object which result in no html to print. Btw the function you provided had a missing }, so I added one.

Try this:

```
function loadVideoList() {
  let playListContainer = $('#playList');
  $.getJSON('http://myserver.com/rest/78', res => {
    if(this.videoList !== res){
      $('#playList').empty();
      this.videoList = res;
      res.videos.forEach((item) => {
       console.log('ok');
        playListContainer.append('<li class="playlist-item"><span class="playlist-item-link" uri="' + item.name + '">' + item.tcsd + '</span></li>');
      });
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this dose not worked. I added a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the javascript before adding the html. I just moved the javascript at the end and it worked